# Gatsby build error 95313 - Project not building

Tags: javascript, build, gatsby

Building error in Gatsby ERROR #95313

Building static HTML failed for path "/components/settings/"

The component that's giving error while building is

```
export const sc = () => {
  if (typeof window == "undefined") return {}
  else
    return {
      lgScr: window.innerHeight >= 901,
      smScr: window.innerHeight >= 635 && window.innerHeight < 900,
      mobile: window.innerWidth < 600,
    }
}
```

Error Log

ERROR

```
Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/components/settings/": {
  "componentChunkName": "component---src-pages-components-settings-js",
  "path": "/components/settings/",
  "result": {
    "pageContext": {}
  },
  "staticQueryHashes": []
}
```

failed Building static HTML for pages - 0.592s

ERROR #95313

Building static HTML failed for path "/components/settings/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html

WebpackError: Minified React error #130;
visit [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]=](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args%5B%5D=object&args%5B%5D=)
for the full message or use the non-minified dev environme  nt for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

- static-entry.js:286
  webpack:/gatsby-starter-hello-world/.cache/static-entry.js:286:22
- utils.js:22
  [gatsby-starter-hello-world]/[@gatsbyjs]/reach-router/es/lib/utils.js:22:1

Answer (score 0):

If it's a component should be capitalized (`Sc`), if it's a standalone function it can be called `sc`. In addition, try to revert the condition. You only want to `return` the `window` data when it's defined (not the same than different than `undefined`, your `else` condition):

```
export const Sc = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  return {
      lgScr: window.innerHeight >= 901,
      smScr: window.innerHeight >= 635 && window.innerHeight < 900,
      mobile: window.innerWidth < 600,
    } 
  }
  else return {}
}
```